# Is this a sufficient proof for the recursion theorem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, induction, recursion

In Paul Halmos "naive set theory" he has a long proof for the recursion theorem. The recursion theorem is

> If $a$ is an element of a set $X$, and if $f$ is a function from $X$
> into $X$, then there exists a function $u$ from $\mathbb{N}$ into $X$
> such that $u(0)=a$ and sucht that $u(n^+)=f(u(n))$ for all $n$ in
> $\mathbb{N}$.

I would just prove it by defining $u$ to be $f^{(n)}(a)$, such that $f^{(0)}(a)=a, f^{(1)}(a)=f(a), f^{(2)}(a)=f(f(a))$, etc.

But in the book the proof is much longer and more complicated. Is what I wrote a legal proof?, if not, why is it not correct?

Comment: The entire content of your argument is in your use of "etc." This is an implicit use of induction which Halmos is taking the time to make explicit. Once you're operating in a setting where you take induction for granted everyone understands the meaning of that "etc." but here Halmos is carefully unpacking it.

Comment: In fact, if you tried to formalize the "etc." part, you would probably be led to making a recursive definition to say what $f^{(n)}(a)$ means, which would be circular with what you're trying to prove here in the first place.  So, the TL/DR of the "much longer and more compliicated" proof is: if you're given induction on $\mathbb{N}$, and you also have the "axiom of unique choice" (which means for each $x \in X$, there exists a unique $y \in Y$ satisfying some condition i$\psi(x,y)$ mplies there exists a function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f(x, f(x))$ for each $x \in X$, then...

Comment: you can construct functions by recursion on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: “I would just prove it by defining $u$ to be $f^{(n)}(a)$”. You have not proved anything. All you have done is come up with new notation $f^{(n)}(a)$. You have failed to rigorously define $f^{(n)}(a)$.